# Unfair downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

@deceze understood the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313574/length-of-string-with-php-without-standard-php-functions) and answered. Why are downvotes ?

After your downvotes I cannot ask questions (system blocked me). If you don't understand the question,  you need downvote?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313574/length-of-string-with-php-without-standard-php-functions  it is the question.

Comment: In a trivial question like that, people would be confused why you couldn't use standard functions that are proved to be better, **unless** you explain the background why you couldn't use them. Edited: o yeah, and also, *minimal code or effort*.

Comment: It is a horrible question because it clearly does not resemble any real-world problem besides strange homework assignments. It also shows zero effort from your side. And just because someone answers a bad question it does not mean he doesn't downvote it, too.

Comment: Don't worry about the question.  It's been deleted now.

Comment: I'm sorry, was it fair?

Comment: please undelete my question, and i will edit the question.

Comment: "If you don't understand the question, you need downvote?" Yes. That's the entire point of a downvote. It's like asking, why do you need to ask questions? Because you want answers, obviously.

Comment: This question was in Olympiad (the same question) . @deceze answered and it was helpfull me. I leave the stackoverflow for all. "thanks" all.

Comment: Your question appears to simply not be "constructive" enough for others. As someone commented, if you can't use the basic functions of PHP, why use PHP at all? I can't see any real-life usage for such a request and probably that's the reason for most the downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

The downvotes you're getting is not because someone didn't understand your question.

I advise you to go through the "help center" and see [what kind of questions should be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to better understand how Stack Overflow works.

You can see the reason of closing your question, it appears below your question:

> Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results.

You didn't demonstrate that, therefore, your question was marked as off-topic. Consider the downvotes as a constructive criticism to correct the way you ask/answer in *stackoverflow*.

Comment: That is no longer a valid close reason BTW.

Comment: @MartinSmith It's not one of the built in close reasons, which is different.  It is still a requirement of questions for them to be on topic, that was never changed; the close reason was simply removed because it was being abused and used to close questions for reasons other than a lack of sufficient understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In reality, any question on Stack Overflow may possibly get an answer/s. That's not the point though. An answered question doesn't make a question on topic here.

If your question is unclear or does not meet certain criteria to be left open and possibly get some upvotes that means there were at least 5 people who voted to close your question. Downvotes are a different story although somehow connected to the fact that people tend to downvote along with a close vote. When hovering over the votes (up and down arrows) you can see the reasons why people *may* downvote a question.

Although *one person* understood your question and decided to answer it, it's a bit unfair towards other community members because any question should be understandable to all, so every one has an equal chance to provide an answer.

Let me tell you what will probably happen now....Your question is already heavily downvoted, closed, and it has some votes indicating that it should be deleted. A few more delete votes from more trusted users and both your question along with the answer will disappear from the site as the community thinks your question is not useful/poor and it does not deserve to be here. The person who answered it will lose the reputation their temporarily gained via your acceptance.

We do not encourage people to answer poor questions. If they are unaware that they are putting them-selfs at risk of just a temporary reputation gain, and give our busy moderators more work to do then they all learn once their answers/questions are deleted and they see the hurtful -15 ( -any upvotes) gone...

If it is possible to improve a question to make it up to the standards than believe me there are many very keen users who submit suggested edits all the time; only if a question is worth it. Yours definitely didn't show enough content to be improved in any way. Your question is very poor. The reason why it has been closed is right below your question. It tells you exactly why it has been closed and what to do to improve your question...

Improving your question:

- Give a brief description of what you were doing when encouraged the problem
- What is your problem specifically related to
- Provide an SSCCE example for your issue
- Include attempted solutions (*tell us what you have tried and what didn't work*)
- We're not mind readers so make sure your question is understandable for all

Once you actually ask a poor question and receive a lot of downvotes it becomes much harder to reverse them even through editing. Although you may revise your question and submit for re-opening you are still starting with negative score. But hey..

You made the effort to improve your question and others agree that it should be reopened. You can then come here, to Meta and somehow gain attention. If you tell us that you're new to site and didn't know how to properly write a question than I am sure good hearted people will give you a few upvotes if you admit your wrong. It's not the right thing to do to come here and complain about downvotes, it's usually better to prove that you have managed to learn from your mistake and now you're more familiar with the site and you will try to ask better quality questions in the future.

Some people tend to answer off-topic questions, poor questions hoping they can get some reputation... Others just want to help, but the truth is that **all questions which do not meet the standards specified within the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) should be downvoted and closed**, therefore always make sure that Stack Overflow is your last resource.

Do your search on google and/or other external sources, try solving it yourself, keep track of what you have tried, learn to demonstrate what you have tried and if you are still stuck your final call is asking a question.